# Scala With Oracle Java removing openjdk dependencies apt-get

Tags: apt, dependencies

I would like to use Oracle JDK and refrain from installing OpenJDK. I attempted to install Scala via the `dpkg` command on the `.deb` file but ended up just unpacking the binaries (manually installing) instead because the debian package wanted me to install openjdk as a dependency.

Now I am getting an error with the package manager saying that I need to install "openjdk-6-jre or java6-runtime" whenever I run the `apt-get upgrade` comand.

Is there a way to fix this dependency issue so that my scala package depends on the installed Oracle JDK? Or can I just remove the entire scala entry in my `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file? Or maybe a way to remove it completely from the apt-cache so that it doesn't throw errors anymore?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Java6 is out of support, you really should keep away from it.

Comment: Will do. Scala is currently using java7 on my machine, it's only the dependency within the debian pm that is suggesting java6

Comment: Is this still a problem?